# Better practices for catching code mistakes with Ember.js (specifically, messed up variable names)

Tags: javascript, ember.js, ember-data

In Ember.js, we use Ember's own object variants which recommend/necessitate using `this.get` and `this.set` in order to access object attributes.

I (mostly) understand why this is done, and appreciate the consistency and flexibility it adds to the Ember programming experience, but I do feel that I lose out on my IDE's sanity checking.

With Jetbrain products (or any good IDE w/ deep analysis and completion) I can usually rely on symbol suggestions to make sure I'm choosing the correct variable name. Entering in strings with ember relies on me to get the name right, and I'm a fallible human.

I have a few thoughts regarding possible solutions.

- Some IDE plugin which does static analysis to suggest the correct string to use
- An ES6 or alternative transpired language which accesses members the ember way by default
- Some way of automatically establishing string constants where I need them
- Some ember debugging setting which at least throws warnings if I try to get a variable which hasn't been defined.
- I would also find it useful to throw warnings if ember catches me trying to set an attribute to undefined.

Hopefully, someone will tell me that one of these solutions exists, something better has been thought of, or my problem isn't really a problem.

(An example to illustrate my problem:)
In the following snippet

```
  const email = this.get('email');

  const newInvitation = this.store.createRecord('invitation', {email: email});
```

I am trying to get the attribute `email` but the real attribute I meant to get was called `emailAddress`. When I create the record, I do so with an undefined email field which isn't caught until later in the code.

It wasn't terrible to debug, but if I have to manually sift through every line of code every time I misspell something, I'm going to waste a lot of time and be a sad debugging-boy. Help!

Comment: Still desperate for input on this, but one solution I've found on my own is [EmberScript](http://emberscript.com/) . I don't believe this solution adequately addresses the premise of my post, because most IDEs aren't going to support EmberScript. While it does replace string lookups with proper identifiers, the value of doing so is made moot because we can't take advantage of it using IDE code analysis. (Also, it's a bit unstable/unmaintained for how invasive of a solution it would be).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Currently we don't have a good solution for this. However the future looks bright!

Currently there is a lot of work going on in the [`ember-typings`](https://github.com/typed-ember/ember-typings) repository to build a typescript definition that will allow the typescript language server to give you that completion. This will give you completions for things like `this.get('foo')` but not for things like `this.get('foo.bar')` in near future.

Also I've build [this](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ember-cli-proxify), which will allow you to omit `.get` and `.set` on browsers that support the [proxy object](http://caniuse.com/#feat=proxy). However this is more a proof-of-concept then something you should use in production!

If you just want debug messages if you access a property thats null you can use `unknownProperty`:

```
unknownProperty(key) {
  console.log('access to unknown property');
}
```

However I sometimes its required to access an unknown property for code like this:

```
if(!obj.get('foo')) {
  obj.set('foo', 'bar');
}
```

---

So overall I would recommend you to try out typescript, because thats probably the solution that will give you a good developer experience soon and good support from the community as well. Interesting is also the [ES classes RFC](https://github.com/emberjs/rfcs/blob/master/text/0240-es-classes.md), that shows, that ember goes toward standard ES classes and at some point we won't `.set` and `.get` at all.
Also glimmer integration is going forward, and inside a glimmer component you won't need `.set` and `.get`.

Also I don't recommend you ember script. I tried it out, but there is basically no-one using it, and no support at all.

Comment: Really great, comprehensive answer, thank you!

I use ts for my Angular2 and React projects and I'd be thrilled if that made my job w/ Ember easier. 

I see what you mean regarding unknownProperty-- is there a way I could set a default in my dev environment builds? Perhaps with `Ember.Object.reopenClass` and defining unknownProperty as you specify (probably with a `console.warn`). Would this cause any problems that you can think of? 

I could probably check membership using `Ember.keys(model.toJSON())` or just suppress specific warnings in my console.

Comment: You could do this, but I would expect this to cause problems because some addons as well as ember core will rely on unknown properties. What you could do is to create a mixing you use in your custom objects (like controllers, components, etc.), that implements that `console.warn`. Also strip it out for production. Im also not sure what you want with `model.toJSON`, but this seems wrong.

Comment: I just mean, in order to check membership properties in my own objects without calling `.get` for an unknown object, I would check membership using `Ember.keys(model.toJSON()).<property>`

Comment: Probably I wouldn't want to write that every time, rather I'd put that into the mixin as you describe.

Comment: But, what is model? Not every object is an model, and so has `toJSON`. Also don't do this, it's slow! Also think about things like the PromiseObject! These things rely on `unknownProperty`